# How to declare and assign the values to a hashMap directly

Tags: java

Like String s="sample" in java.How to declare and assign values to a hashMap in one step. Also is it possible to assign more set of values at a time using put function in hashMap.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it is possible. you can use the below code

```
HashMap<String,String> instruments = new HashMap<String, String>() {
{
        put("test","test");
        put("test1","test1");
}
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a library like Google Guava which has lots of utilities to instantiate HashMaps. It is also possible doing anonymous inheritance like this:

```
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("Test", "Test1");
        put("Test", "Test1");
    }};
```

But I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

such constructs do not exist in good ol' java.

On one hand, you can use `property files format` for that. You can save your map as a something-separated key-value pairs in a string or a file, and read them in a loop filling your map with each pair.

on the other hand, if you really need that + possible type-checking, you can look at modern dynamic JVM languages, like `Groovy` or `Scala`.

there you can use the code as it is:

```
def map = [ a:1, b:23, c:"aasdasd" ]
```